# Even as in “is there even”

Tags: grammar

There are a lot of ways to expres the English word “even”, but I am not sure which one to use in the meaning of:

- What’s this? Is it *even* food?
- Is there *even* a way get out of here?
- Does such a person *even* exist?

It looks like neither も or さえ fit here as they correspond to a different “even”. I can only come up with plain unflavored sentences that don’t include the intended, slightly sarcastic doubt.

- 食物ですか。
- ここを出る方法がありますか。
- そんな人がいますか。

How can I change those to inject this meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the adverb [そもそも](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%82%E3%81%9D%E3%82%82) is the word you are looking for. You can use this both in informal and formal situations.

- これは何？　そもそも食べ物なの？
- そもそもここを出る方法はあるのですか？
- そもそもそんな人間はいるのだろうか。